# In some viewports, how to get slider image to same height as parent div?

Tags: css

In the snippet below, I have a slider. Half the slider is static text, and the other half is images. When the viewport hits 768px, the images go to a different height and doesn't take on the full height of the div. I've tried `object-fit`, but it's not going to the height of the div. I'm trying to get the effect of `background-size: cover;`, but I'm using an image tag instead of a background image.

**How do I get the image to go the full height of the div, without distorting the image?**

```js
//slides
let slideIndex = 0;
document.querySelector('.slideshow') ? showSlides() : null;

function showSlides() {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow__slide");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";    
  setTimeout(showSlides, 4000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 2.5rem
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 3.75rem
  }
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2.25rem
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  h2 {
    font-size: 3rem
  }
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.5rem
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  h3 {
    font-size: 2.25rem
  }
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.25rem
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  h4 {
    font-size: 1.75rem
  }
}

h5 {
  font-size: 1rem
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  h5 {
    font-size: 1.25rem
  }
}

h6 {
  font-size: 1rem
}

.slider-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}

.slider-box__left,
.slider-box__right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1
}

.slider-box__left {
  order: 2
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .slider-box__left {
    order: 1
  }
}

.slider-box__right {
  order: 1
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .slider-box__right {
    order: 2
  }
}

.slider-box__right .slideshow {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto
}

.slider-box__right .slideshow__slide {
  display: none
}

.slider-box__right .slideshow__slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto!important;
  object-fit: contain
}

.slider-box__right .slideshow__slide.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1s
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.slider-box__left--content {
  display: flex;
  background: #9dc344;
  padding: .5rem
}

.slider-box__left--inner {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .5rem
}

.slider-box__left--inner .logo-icon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}

.slider-box__left--inner .logo-icon img {
  max-width: 300px
}

.slider-box__left hr {
  width: 2rem;
  background: #fff
}

.slider-box__left--title {
  text-align: center
}

.slider-box__left--title h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .slider-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row
  }
}

@media(min-width: 1024px) {
  .slider-box {
    width: 1200px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="slider-box">
    <div class="slider-box__left">
      <div class="slider-box__left--content">
        <div class="slider-box__left--inner">
          <div class="logo-icon">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/Logo-color-300x100.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="slider-box__left--title">
            <h3>Pharmaceutical Compliance you can trust</h3>
            <hr>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam rem, iusto voluptatem necessitatibus
              saepe a.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-box__right">
      <div class="slideshow">
        <div class="slideshow__slide fade">
          <img src="https://jordan-pharma-dev.web.app/img/pharmacist-business-meeting.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slideshow__slide fade">
          <img src="https://jordan-pharma-dev.web.app/img/pharmacist-conference.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slideshow__slide fade">
          <img src="https://jordan-pharma-dev.web.app/img/pharmacists-working.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slideshow__slide fade">
          <img src="https://jordan-pharma-dev.web.app/img/fda-stamp.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slideshow__slide fade">
          <img src="https://jordan-pharma-dev.web.app/img/single-pharmacist-working.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `height: auto!important;` on `img` elements means set height of the parent container to image size no matter what. But we want the opposite. So, use `height: 100%`.

In order to set parent containers' heights we can use `window.onresize` event. In following code see the `/* ... */` comments in CSS for changes:

```js
//slides
let slideIndex = 0;
document.querySelector('.slideshow') ? showSlides() : null;

function showSlides() {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow__slide");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";    
  setTimeout(showSlides, 4000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}

window.onresize = function resizeHandler(){
  const left = document.querySelector('.slider-box__left--content');
  const right = document.querySelector('.slider-box__right');
  right.style.height = `${left.clientHeight}px`;
  right.style.width = `${left.clientWidth}px`;
}
```

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 2.5rem
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 3.75rem
  }
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2.25rem
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  h2 {
    font-size: 3rem
  }
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.5rem
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  h3 {
    font-size: 2.25rem
  }
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.25rem
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  h4 {
    font-size: 1.75rem
  }
}

h5 {
  font-size: 1rem
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  h5 {
    font-size: 1.25rem
  }
}

h6 {
  font-size: 1rem
}

.slider-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}

.slider-box__left,
.slider-box__right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1
}

.slider-box__left {
  order: 2
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .slider-box__left {
    order: 1
  }
}

.slider-box__right {
  order: 1
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .slider-box__right {
    order: 2
  }
}

.slider-box__right .slideshow {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.slider-box__right .slideshow__slide {
  display: none;
  
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.slider-box__right .slideshow__slide img {
  width: 100%;
  /*height: auto!important;*/
  /*object-fit: contain;*/
  object-fit: cover;
  
  height: 100%;
}

.slider-box__right .slideshow__slide.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1s
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.slider-box__left--content {
  display: flex;
  background: #9dc344;
  padding: .5rem
}

.slider-box__left--inner {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .5rem
}

.slider-box__left--inner .logo-icon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}

.slider-box__left--inner .logo-icon img {
  max-width: 300px
}

.slider-box__left hr {
  width: 2rem;
  background: #fff
}

.slider-box__left--title {
  text-align: center
}

.slider-box__left--title h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .slider-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row
  }
}

@media(min-width: 1024px) {
  .slider-box {
    width: 1200px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-box">
    <div class="slider-box__left">
      <div class="slider-box__left--content">
        <div class="slider-box__left--inner">
          <div class="logo-icon">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/Logo-color-300x100.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="slider-box__left--title">
            <h3>Pharmaceutical Compliance you can trust</h3>
            <hr>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam rem, iusto voluptatem necessitatibus
              saepe a.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-box__right">
      <div class="slideshow">
        <div class="slideshow__slide fade">
          <img src="https://jordan-pharma-dev.web.app/img/pharmacist-business-meeting.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slideshow__slide fade">
          <img src="https://jordan-pharma-dev.web.app/img/pharmacist-conference.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slideshow__slide fade">
          <img src="https://jordan-pharma-dev.web.app/img/pharmacists-working.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slideshow__slide fade">
          <img src="https://jordan-pharma-dev.web.app/img/fda-stamp.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slideshow__slide fade">
          <img src="https://jordan-pharma-dev.web.app/img/single-pharmacist-working.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Play with [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit#values) values to achieve desired image shapes.

Comment: I adjusted the width and the max-width in the 1024px media query from 1200px to 1024px because it was creating an overflow. That was my bad as it was in the OP. Thanks for your help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...

It was a bit tricky to get the desired output. You need to add/remove/change a few lines of your CSS (see comments below), but the main thing is that you need to set the height of the `.slider-box` if you want `object-fit: cover;` to work. I also simplified your HTML structure a little bit.

See the snippet below.

```js
// Slides
let slideIndex = 0;
document.querySelector('.slideshow') ? showSlides() : null;

function showSlides() {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow__slide");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 4000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 3.75rem;
  }
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2.25rem;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  h2 {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  h3 {
    font-size: 2.25rem;
  }
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  h4 {
    font-size: 1.75rem;
  }
}

h5 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  h5 {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
  }
}

h6 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.slider-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 380px; /* Add this */
}

.slider-box__left,
.slider-box__right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.slider-box__left {
  order: 2;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .slider-box__left {
    order: 1;
  }
}

.slider-box__right {
  order: 1;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .slider-box__right {
    order: 2;
  }
}

.slider-box__right .slideshow {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Remove this */
/*
.slider-box__right .slideshow__slide {
  display: none
}

.slider-box__right .slideshow__slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto!important;
  object-fit: contain
}
*/

.slider-box__right .slideshow__slide.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.slider-box__left--content {
  display: flex;
  background: #9dc344;
  padding: .5rem;
  height: 100%; /* Add this */
}

.slider-box__left--inner {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.slider-box__left--inner .logo-icon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slider-box__left--inner .logo-icon img {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.slider-box__left hr {
  width: 2rem;
  background: #fff;
}

.slider-box__left--title {
  text-align: center;
}

.slider-box__left--title h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .slider-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 100px;
  }
}

@media(min-width: 1024px) {
  .slider-box {
    width: 1200px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    height: 400px; /* Add this */
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  /* Add this */
  .slideshow {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  /* Add this */
  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  
  /* Add this */
  .slider-box__right .slideshow__slide {
    display: none;
  }
  
  /* Add this */
  .slider-box__right .slideshow__slide img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}

/* Add this */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .slider-box__right .slideshow__slide {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .slider-box__right .slideshow__slide {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-box">
  <div class="slider-box__left">
    <div class="slider-box__left--content">
      <div class="slider-box__left--inner">
        <div class="logo-icon">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/Logo-color-300x100.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slider-box__left--title">
          <h3>Pharmaceutical Compliance you can trust</h3>
          <hr>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam rem, iusto voluptatem necessitatibus saepe a.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-box__right">
    <div class="slideshow">
      <img class="slideshow__slide fade" src="https://jordan-pharma-dev.web.app/img/pharmacist-business-meeting.jpg" alt="">
      <img class="slideshow__slide fade" src="https://jordan-pharma-dev.web.app/img/pharmacist-conference.jpg" alt="">
      <img class="slideshow__slide fade" src="https://jordan-pharma-dev.web.app/img/pharmacists-working.jpg" alt="">
      <img class="slideshow__slide fade" src="https://jordan-pharma-dev.web.app/img/fda-stamp.jpg" alt="">
      <img class="slideshow__slide fade" src="https://jordan-pharma-dev.web.app/img/single-pharmacist-working.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer:

```js
let slideIndex = 0;
document.querySelector('.slideshow') ? showSlides() : null;

function showSlides() {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow__slide");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 4000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 3.75rem;
  }
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2.25rem;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  h2 {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  h3 {
    font-size: 2.25rem;
  }
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  h4 {
    font-size: 1.75rem;
  }
}

h5 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  h5 {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
  }
}

h6 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.slider-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 380px; /* Add this */
}

.slider-box__left,
.slider-box__right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.slider-box__left {
  order: 2;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .slider-box__left {
    order: 1;
  }
}

.slider-box__right {
  order: 1;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .slider-box__right {
    order: 2;
  }
}

.slider-box__right .slideshow {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Remove this */
/*
.slider-box__right .slideshow__slide {
  display: none
}

.slider-box__right .slideshow__slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto!important;
  object-fit: contain
}
*/

.slider-box__right .slideshow__slide.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.slider-box__left--content {
  display: flex;
  background: #9dc344;
  padding: .5rem;
  height: 100%; /* Add this */
}

.slider-box__left--inner {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.slider-box__left--inner .logo-icon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slider-box__left--inner .logo-icon img {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.slider-box__left hr {
  width: 2rem;
  background: #fff;
}

.slider-box__left--title {
  text-align: center;
}

.slider-box__left--title h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .slider-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 100px;
  }
}

@media(min-width: 1024px) {
  .slider-box {
    width: 1200px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    height: 400px; /* Add this */
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  .slideshow {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  
  .slider-box__right .slideshow__slide {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .slider-box__right .slideshow__slide img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .slider-box__right .slideshow__slide {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .slider-box__right .slideshow__slide {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-box">
  <div class="slider-box__left">
    <div class="slider-box__left--content">
      <div class="slider-box__left--inner">
        <div class="logo-icon">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/Logo-color-300x100.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slider-box__left--title">
          <h3>Pharmaceutical Compliance you can trust</h3>
          <hr>
          <p>What text you want</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-box__right">
    <div class="slideshow">
      <img class="slideshow__slide fade" src="https://jordan-pharma-dev.web.app/img/pharmacist-business-meeting.jpg" alt="">
      <img class="slideshow__slide fade" src="https://jordan-pharma-dev.web.app/img/pharmacist-conference.jpg" alt="">
      <img class="slideshow__slide fade" src="https://jordan-pharma-dev.web.app/img/pharmacists-working.jpg" alt="">
      <img class="slideshow__slide fade" src="https://jordan-pharma-dev.web.app/img/fda-stamp.jpg" alt="">
      <img class="slideshow__slide fade" src="https://jordan-pharma-dev.web.app/img/single-pharmacist-working.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```